# Como especifico el tamaño de una cadena de caracteres en vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, .net

Tengo la siguiente duda, en visual basic para aplicaciones (VBA), como por ejemplo el de excel, para fijar el tamaño de una cadena de caracteres, se hacia al declarar la variable y multiplicarla por el numero, tal como lo muestro aqui:

Dim a As String * 5

Esto significa que mi variable va a tener un tamaño fijo de 5 caracteres.

Ahora bien, al programar en vb.net (en visual studio 2013) quiero hacer lo mismo, pero me sale un error.¿sera que lo estoy haciendo bien?, lo estoy haciendo asi:

Dim prueba As String * 5

¿ya no esta disponible esta funcion para esta version? Agradecido por la ayuda

Comment: Hola, por acá dan un par de ejemplos como hacerlo [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305377/how-to-declare-a-fixed-length-string-in-vb-net]

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto, no se puede.

Podrias declarar un vector de bytes fijo para circunscribir este problema:

```
Dim Buff(5) as byte
```

Pero tenes que tomarte el trabajo de pasarle los datos usando un objeto de la clase `Encoding` (por ejemplo `System.Text.UTF8Encoding`).

Tambien podes usar < VBFixedString(5)> (mira [aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.vbfixedstringattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)), pero es solo para información y no fuerza realmente el tamaño.

Una tercera opcion, es que uses un [stringbuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8). Y le pases el tamaño que quieras que tenga el string.